# What tools are available for managing a Hyper-V server?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I've configured my Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 server for remote management using Hyper-V manager but when compared to the ESXi client, Hyper-V manager seems to be missing a bunch of host management functionality.

What tools and methods are available for managing an Hyper-V server?

Comment: PowerShell ALL THE THINGS!!!!!

Comment: Missing what exactly? How about Hyper-V Manager? How about SCVMM?

Comment: How might I configure the physical NICs on the server?

Comment: OK, you're asking a lot of questions. How are the network cards related to managing the server?

Comment: Granted that managing a Hyper-V host is quite a bit different from managing a vSphere host, but perhaps you could ask more specific questions. What are you trying to manage? Creating a virtual switch? Use Hyper-V Manager or PowerShell. Creating a virtual machine? Use Hyper-V Manager or PowerShell. Etc., etc.

Comment: `How might I configure the physical NICs on the server?` - Issue the correct Powershell commands to configure the network interfaces.

Comment: I'm asking one question. How would I manage the configuration of the physical host. For example, how might I enable Jumbo Frames on the physical NIC. In the ESXi world, this would be done in the vSphere client.

Comment: Powershell.  For Jumbo Frames see http://workinghardinit.wordpress.com/2012/06/11/configuring-jumbo-frames-with-powershell-in-windows-server-2012/

Comment: You are not seeing the forest for the trees. Hyper-V does not need anything special for configuring items like you mention, as they are just configured through any/all the normal methods you use to configure Windows Server. Those settings are part of the OS and Hyper-V does not need to provide a way to manage separately or in addition to the comprehensive options that the OS already provides.

Answer (score 1):

[5nine](http://www.5nine.com/5nine-manager-for-hyper-v-free.aspx), [Veeam](http://www.veeam.com/virtual-server-management-one-free.html), [manageengine](http://www.manageengine.com/free-hyper-v-configuration/free-hyper-v-configuration-index.html) etc all offer some limited/free edition HyperV management tools. If you search on google, I'm sure you will find tons more. I'd suggest you try each one and compare with the built in HyperV manager. Compare to see what's missing and what is more flexible. If they fit your needs, you can purchase the full version. Hope this helps.